# Vue Calling function of the child component when rendering the child component in v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to call the method of the child component.
I think that the developer uses `$nextTick` function to process the data after all child component rendered.
But how could I call the method of the child component when rendering by `v-if` directive.
Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lehqv64f/3/).

```js
var comp = Vue.component('child', {
 data:function(){
   return {
     
    }
  },
  template:`
   <div class="child">
     I'm a child
    </div>
  `,
  methods:{
   callFunction:function(){
     console.log("I'm called");
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
 el:'#app',
  data:{
   if_child:false
  },  
  methods:{
   showChild(){
     this.if_child = !this.if_child;
      //Calling child's function
      this.$refs.child.callFunction();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.child{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  background:#eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="if_child">
    <child ref="child" class="child"></child>  
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="showChild">
    Toggle Child
  </button>
</div>
```

When I trying to call the method `callFunction()` of the child component in `showChild()` , it throws an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callFunction' of undefined

I think that the reason is because it calls the function of the child component before rendering the child component.
How could I solve this issue? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the question, `$nextTick` is the solution here.

Vue batches together rendering. When you change reactive data, such as `if_child`, it won't immediately cause any rendering to happen. Instead the component is added to a list of components that need rendering. Once you've finished making all your data changes Vue will render all the components in the list.

There are two reasons for this. Firstly, rendering is quite expensive. Secondly, if you're in the middle of updating your data then it might be in an inconsistent state that can't be rendered correctly.

The name 'rendering' is a little misleading. It makes it sound a bit like drawing something. However, it also includes things like creating and destroying child components.

The `$refs` are updated just after a component renders. This all happens at the start of the next tick. To wait for that we use `$nextTick`.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div class="child">
      I'm a child
    </div>
  `,
  
  methods: {
    callFunction () {
      console.log("I'm called");
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    if_child: false
  },
  
  methods: {
    showChild () {
      this.if_child = !this.if_child;
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        const child = this.$refs.child;
        
        if (child) {
          child.callFunction();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="if_child">
    <child ref="child" class="child"></child>  
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="showChild">
    Toggle Child
  </button>
</div>
```

Here's the key section:

```js
showChild () {
  this.if_child = !this.if_child;

  this.$nextTick(() => {
    const child = this.$refs.child;

    if (child) {
      child.callFunction();
    }
  });
}
```

You might wonder why it needs the `if (child) {`. That's because the button toggles the value of `if_child`. The method name, `showChild`, is actually misleading. The first time you click the button the child is created but the next time you click it will be destroyed.

If you don't pass a callback to `$nextTick` it will return a promise instead. This allows it to be used with `async`/`await` if you prefer:

```js
async showChild () {
  this.if_child = !this.if_child;

  await this.$nextTick();

  const child = this.$refs.child;

  if (child) {
    child.callFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought that the `$nextTick()` could be used in only `mounted` hook function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Why it doesn't work ?**

because when your `v-if` is on the `false` state your child component doesn't exist. Vue hasn’t created it yet so your `ref` child is still undefined which means the `callFunction` won't be executed (`undefined`)

**how about using Vue.nextTick API ?**

i tried implementing it on the code (i tried both synchronous and asynchronous syntax) , but it works only on the first attempt then the child `ref` became `undefined` again ... it's because the component got destroyed (after `if_child` turned to `false`) so ´ref´ will be ´undefined´.

**How can i fix this ?**

I found two ways that can solve your problem  :

1 - by using `v-show` on your child instead of `v-if` ... this will make your child always available(always rendered so your `ref` will be always defined) with a `display : none` on the false state;

2 - however if you insist on using `v-if` you can add another variable that will be mutated when the DOM finish rendering (using nextTick API) ... and your child component will watch that variable and execute the function upon that ... here is how you can do it :

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['exe'],
  watch: {
    exe() {
      this.callFunction()
    }
  },
  template: `
   <div class="child">
     I'm a child
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    callFunction: function() {
      console.log("I'm called");
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    if_child: false,
    executeTheChildFunction: false,
  },
  methods: {
    showChild() {
      this.if_child = !this.if_child;
      //Calling child's function
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.executeTheChildFunction = !this.executeTheChildFunction;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="if_child">
    <child id="child" class="child" :exe="executeTheChildFunction"></child>
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="showChild">
    Toggle Child
  </button>
</div>
```